# jquery fadeIn Moves Images to New Line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery fadeIn/Out script here:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){         
    $("#home li").hover(
        function(){ $("img", this).fadeIn("400"); }, 
        function() { $("img", this).fadeOut("400"); } 
    );
});
```

With CSS here:

```
#home a:hover img{
  width:210px;
}

#home a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}

#home img {
  width:0px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

#home { 
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:right;
  font-family: JeanLucWeb-Thin;
  font-size:75px;
  line-height:80%;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="main">
<center>
<ul id="home">
    <li><a href="news.php"><img src="images/header_1.png" alt=""/>NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php"><img src="images/header_2.png" alt=""/>ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="adventuresofpaulandmarian.php"><img src="images/header_3.png" alt=""/>FILM</a></li>
    <li><a href="bardybunch.php"><img src="images/header_4.png" alt=""/>THEATER</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php"><img src="images/header_5.png" alt=""/>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</center>
</div>
```

You can view the end result here: http://michaelherbig.com/jaystern/index.php

This issue is that when you hover over the link, it seems to add a new line after the image that fades in.  Without the JavaScript, the end result looks fine, meaning no new line, but I'd like to have the fade effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are getting set to `display:block` during the animation. Prevent this with the following:

```
/* Line 28 of layout.css */
#home img {
  width:0px;
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#home img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: That got rid of the new line, although now it's way over to the left (obviously).  I'd really hate to do negative margins on this, but it'll work.

Could you explain what is going on?  Why is there a new line with the javascript but not without it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```css
#home img {
  width:0px;
  margin-right:10px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```